# How can I hide or diminish VS2017's vertical lines in the editor

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 uses quite bright, dashed, vertical lines within code's indentation to highlight the extent of various scopes.

[image]

How can I turn these off, or make them less vivid?

Answer (score 8):

You can reduce the intensity of these lines:

[image]

In VS2017, go to menu *Tools, Options...*.

Navigate to *Environment/Fonts and Colors* and scroll to select the *Structure Guide Lines* display item.

[image]

Click custom, then drag down the black arrow to the right of the dialog until you see a colour you like.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also turn them off completely from Tools\Options, Text Editor, General, Show structure guide lines.